# Setting UIAppearance is not effecting cocoapod UI component

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios11, uiappearance

I am currently working on an app, which uses an cocoapod UI component. All my efforts to change the appearance (custom font) of the contained labels failed so far. 
Does anybody have experienced a positive result? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You could start by telling us which component it is...

Comment: Just say you have a cocoa pod with a custom UIView, containing a UILabel. Now you want to use this custom view in your app, which has its UILabel UIAppearance set to a custom font, color, etc. Simple example:  `UILabel.appearance().textColor = .red`. Additionally imagine you cannot access the custom view directly, because it is instantiated by some kind of factory.

Comment: `UILabel.appearanceWhenContained(in: [NameOfCustomView.self]).textColor = .red` You might need to adjust the hierarchy. An alternative is to fork the project, add whatever you want and send a Pull Request, or point your podfile to your own repo.

Answer (score 0):

IF a label has a custom font setter you cannot change its font using UIAppearance, you can only change it if no-font is selected.

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstood my question. Check my additional comment.